# How do I make sure that my footer shows all the way at end of the page rather than in the middle?

Tags: html, css, footer

Here's my footer css:

```
 .footer {
      background-color: #CACACA;
      font-size: 20px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      }
```

On multiple pages I have containers that content text.  On some pages there is just enough content that the footer appears at the end of the page.  But in some cases there isn't enough content so the footer still shows under the container but there is a gap between that and the end of the page.  How can I fix this so it adjusts regardless of the length of the container?

Comment: did you try: bottom: 0px?

Comment: @mario I tried margin-bottom: 0px;

Comment: i have added and updated my answer, now you can see it with loads of content and with barely any. Good Luck!

Comment: @connormiles Thanks man! I'll see if I can work with it and post you here!

Comment: @KPO: i didnt wrote margin. you have to set the position, not the space to the parent :)

Comment: @KPO If you have solved this problem, please either pick the correct answer from the answers below, or please post your own answer if you have solved this yourself, that way this question is not down as unanswered. 

If you still haven't solved your issue give us some more details,

All the best.

                         Connor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like so

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Amazing Footer</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       height:100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;
    }
    footer{
        background:#F1F1F1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height:300px;
    }

    footer p{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="Content">
            <p>HTML Ipsum Presents</p>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; My Website 2013. All Rights Reserved!</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

see we have the footer in the wrapper and the footer is absolute to the bottom and left of the wrapper then we just add the height of the footer to the wrapper bottom padding and some default height on the wrapper and body and that's sorted, take a look on jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/eTwJh/2/ and here is one with no content - http://jsfiddle.net/eTwJh/3/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the corresponding HTML, it's a bit hard to guess what your issues might be.  It sounds like there's a bottom margin on your main content that's pushing the page bottom downward past the footer when there's only limited content inside that main section.

To fix it, either adjust that margin or else change the positioning of the footer.  At the moment, the position is absolute, which means that the footer is positioned based upon the its parent element in the HTML.  Switching the positioning to relative will make it appear just after whatever element comes just before it in the HTML.

I suggest you read [more about CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) before trying to work on the issue further.