# CSS - How to make footer stay at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

the layout here is a template for my website http://jsfiddle.net/QvFV8/12/ as you can see the content overflows the footer.

It works fine for when there is only a small amount of content, which is what I want.
I've tried clear both in the 1st footer section, but this has no effect

How can the page be stretched so that the footer remains at the bottom, regardless of the amount of content (some pages will have more or less content then others)

```
<body> 
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerleft">
            <div class="headerleftcon">leftcon</div>
            </div>
        <div class="headerright">
            <div class="headerrightcon">rightcon</div>
            </div>
        <div class="header-content">Header
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="body">
        <div class="left-sidebar">
            <div class="left-content">left sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-sidebar">
            <div class="right-content">right sidebar</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">Content 1
        <div class="centerbox">
            <div class="centerboxcontent">Center box <br>  </div>
        </div>Content 2 <br> Content 2 <br>Content 2 <br>Content 2 <br>Content 2  
        bla bla bla
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerleft">
            <div class="footerleftcon">botleftcon</div>
            </div>
        <div class="footerright">
            <div class="footerrightcon">botrightcon</div>
            </div>
        <div class="footer-content">Footer</div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

The css is as follows

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}
.header, .footer{
height: 80px;
background-color: #EFEFEF;
position: relative;}
.header-content{
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;}
.headerleft{
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
float: left;}
.headerleftcon{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.headerright{
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
float: right;}
.headerrightcon{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.footer-content{
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;}
.container{
height: 100%;}
.body{
height: 100%;
margin-top: -80px;
margin-bottom: -80px;
background-color: #C7DFFA;} 
.content{
padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;}
.left-sidebar{
height: 100%;
background-color: gray;
width: 50px;
margin-top: -80px;
margin-bottom: -80px;
float: left;
clear: both;} 
.right-sidebar{
height: 100%;
background-color: gray;
width: 50px;
margin-top: -80px;
margin-bottom: -80px;
float: right;}
.centerbox{
height:100px;
background-color: blue;}
.centerboxcontent{
padding:  0px 0px 0px 0px;} 
.right-content{
padding:  80px 0px 0px 0px;
text-align: right;}
.left-content{
padding:  80px 0px 0px 0px;} 
.footer{
   clear:both;}
.footerleft{
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
float: left;}
.footerleftcon{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.footerright{
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
float: right;}
.footerrightcon{
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.header, .footer {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.header-content {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.headerleft {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.headerleftcon {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.headerright {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
.headerrightcon {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.footer-content {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.body {
    background-color: #C7DFFA;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
    padding-bottom: 30000px;
}
.content {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.left-sidebar {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.right-sidebar {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
.left-sidebar, .right-sidebar {
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
    padding-bottom: 30000px;
}
.centerbox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.centerboxcontent {
    padding:  0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.right-content {
    text-align: right;
}
.left-content {
}
.footer {
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.footerleft {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.footerleftcon {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.footerright {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
.footerrightcon {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that getting the footer of a website is somewhat harder than anything else, but i don't know how many more questions i have to see about this, its simply a call for learning CSS, now here are two fiddles that i have made before for the same question

So, what you have to do is make sure your footer is absolutely at the bottom of your container, so to do that you need to make your container position:relative; and 100% height of the content Also the container has to have a padding bottom that is the height of the footer . that's it really

http://jsfiddle.net/eTwJh/2/ and here is one with no content - http://jsfiddle.net/eTwJh/3/

The duplicate question is here

[How do I make sure that my footer shows all the way at end of the page rather than in the middle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179998/how-do-i-make-sure-that-my-footer-shows-all-the-way-at-end-of-the-page-rather-th/15180121#15180121)

here is some example code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Amazing Footer</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       height:100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;
    }
    footer{
        background:#F1F1F1;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height:300px;
    }

    footer p{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="Content">
            <p>HTML Ipsum Presents</p>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; My Website 2013. All Rights Reserved!</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JustDon't, Have you tested in IE7, IE8?

Comment: @RGS This was nearly a year ago i don't remember