# Lots of unused space below my footer "div"

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a footer div on my master page. It kinda works, but when i run my website, there's a lot of unused space below my footer. How can i remove it? I'm using vs2012. For some reason i can't use jsfiddle at work. Sorry for the long post.

[image]

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Território Levita - Portal</title>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/StyleMaster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><a href="#">Território Levita - Portal</a></h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menuNav">
            <ul>
                <li class="ativo"><a href="#">Principal</a></li>
                <li class="temsub"><a href="#">Eventos</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">´~~´ç55,,.\\Visualizar Eventos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Manter Eventos</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="temsub"><a href="#">Dados Pessoais</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Visualizar dados Pessoais</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="conteudo">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h3>"Mas, no tocante às cidades, às casas das cidades da sua possessão, direito perpétuo de resgate terão os levitas." Levítico 25:32 </h3>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 768px;
}



#header { /*Estilo do cabeçalho*/
    background-color: #67BCDB; /*Cor de fundo*/
    width: 95%; /*Comprimento - 95% da tela*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Margin: espaçamento entre o elemento e outro - tá 0 para top e bottom, e auto para left e right (alinha no centro)*/
    height: 80px; /*Altura do header*/
    line-height: 80px; /*Tamanho da linha. Como tá igual à altura, o texto fica no meio.*/
    padding-left: 20px; /*Espaço entre a borda do header e o conteúdo - o elemento A*/
}

    #header a { /*Estilo do texto do cabeçalho*/
        text-decoration: none; /*Sem decoração no texto*/
        color: #fff; /*Cor branca*/
    }


#menuNav {
    margin-left: 23px;
}
/*Menu*/
#menuNav > ul {
    list-style: none; /*Tirando o estilo da lista de dentro da div*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: 1;
}

#menuNav > ul { /*Container*/
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

    #menuNav > ul li { /*Contem links*/
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 150px;
    }

    #menuNav > ul  li  a { /*Estilo dos botões "pais"*/
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #d9d9d9;
        padding: 11px 20px;
        width: 100px;
        /*Tipografia*/
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #3dafea;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
        background: #eaeaea;
    }

        #menuNav > ul > li > a:hover, #menuNav > ul > li:hover > a { /*Quando o mouse estiver por cima*/
            color: #fff; /*Cor de texto branca*/
            background: #54cdf1; /*Muda a cor de fundo para um azul*/
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3); /*Gradientes para cor de fundo.*/
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #54cdf1, #74d7f3);
            border-color: transparent; /*Tira as bordas*/
        }

    /*A seta do submenu*/
    #menuNav > ul .temsub > a::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #3dafea;
    }

    #menuNav > ul .temsub > a::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 17px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        /* Creating the arrow using borders */
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    }

    /* Changing the color of the arrow on hover */
    #menuNav > ul li > a:hover::after, #menuNav > ul li:hover > a::after {
        border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    }

    #menuNav > ul li > a:hover::before, #menuNav > ul li:hover > a::before {
        border-left: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    }

    /*submenus*/
    #menuNav > ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        top: -9999px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
    }

    /* Showing the submenu when the user is hovering the parent link */
        #menuNav > ul li:hover>ul {
            top: 0px;
            opacity: 1;
        }

#conteudo {
    margin: 25px 50px 0 50px;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}

/*Rodapé*/
#footer {
    clear:both;
    width: 95%;
    height: 80px; /*Altura do header*/
    line-height: 80px;
    background-color: #67BCDB;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: center;    
}

    #footer h3 {
        color: #FFF;
    }
```

Comment: [Sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) will fix this

Comment: Moar Lorem Ipsum will fix this.

Comment: what happens when you change the `body`'s `min-height: 768px;` to a smaller value?

Comment: i've addded min-height and min-width in body for when the user resizes the window, my components don't roam around the screen

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179998/how-do-i-make-sure-that-my-footer-shows-all-the-way-at-end-of-the-page-rather-th/15180121#15180121

Comment: +1 to @RaraituL, I have implemented something very similar to this and works greate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the rule below from `body`:

```
min-height: 768px;
```

- [FIDDLE DEMO **BEFORE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/8kudP/)
- [FIDDLE DEMO **AFTER**](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/8kudP/1)

Also you have `line-height` for your `footer`. Remove it to remove the spaces after footer completely ([FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/8kudP/2/)). You can add `padding-top: 10px;` to style your footer as you want.

Answer (score 1):

As tends to be the case with computer problems, it's doing exactly what you told it, but that isn't what you want! `;)`

The `min-height` property in the `body` part of the CSS file is set to `768px`.  Thus, the webpage will always be at least `768px` tall--if there's not enough content, it just tags on additional whitespace at the footer.

**To fix your problem**, either reduce or remove the `min-height`.

Comment: it works *-* 
but if the user resizes the page, my components will wander around the page as it goes...how can i solve this ?

Comment: That doesn't occur on my simulation of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Give the footer h3 a height of 30px

Comment: or 80px. Making it the full height of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

to your footer css